# Vue JS provide/inject and Props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When should provide/inject be used compared to props.

In my opinion props make component more meaningful.

Provide/inject makes components tightly coupled.

What are the use cases where using provide/inject is a better approach.

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some differences that helped me choose in many situations

1. **props are reactive and provide / inject is not.**
2. **props can only be used on direct child components.**

From docs:

> Provide / inject are used together to allow an ancestor component to serve as a dependency injector for all its descendants, regardless of how deep the component hierarchy is, as long as they are in the same parent chain. If you are familiar with React, this is very similar to React’s context feature.

3. **You can use provide / inject to set a default value for props.**

example:

```
const Child = {
  inject: ['foo'],
  props: {
    bar: {
      default () {
        return this.foo
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Here](https://medium.com/js-dojo/the-magic-of-provide-inject-a27041df33b2) is an article of a good example when to use provide / inject

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are props reactive ? I was under the impression that only data properties are reactive. If props are reactive why do we need to watch them for any changes that occur to them in parent components from which they are passed ? Please clarify

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/pull/862

Comment: Provide/inject is reactive since 2020.