# Provide/Inject vs props in Vue 3: are they functionally exchangeable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As far as I am aware, the main reason props were favored over the Provide/Inject API was the fact that the latter weren't reactive ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/7p8wib/why_not_use_provideinject/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468077/vue-js-provide-inject-and-props#:%7E:text=props%20can%20only%20be%20used%20on%20direct%20child%20components.&text=Provide%20%2F%20inject%20are%20used%20together,in%20the%20same%20parent%20chain.), [3](https://medium.com/js-dojo/the-magic-of-provide-inject-a27041df33b2)). However, this seems to [have changed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#reactivity) recently. Now that you can make them reactive, is there any difference in functionality between the two?